# Using JavaScript with asp.net pages

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have probably very simple question.

I have copied that code to my asp.net web application project but i couln't minimize the box.

Is there anything special i should do to use javascript with asp.net projects?

I tried the code tree times.

1. Put script code in to head block
2. Put script code to just before div starts
3. Put script code to just before form tag closes

Javascript code

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
});
```

html code

```
<div id="widnow">
    <div id="title_bar"> Basic information
        <div id="button"><img src="http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Minus_in_circle.svg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

css code

```
#widnow{
    width:400px;
    border:solid 1px;
}

#title_bar{
    background: #FEFEFE;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
#button{
    border:solid 1px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 23px;
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#box{
    height: 250px;
    background: #DFDFDF;
}
```

Comment: Sample here http://jsfiddle.net/miqdad/Qy6Sj/1/

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle. Do you have the jQuery referenced in your project?

Comment: Did you include a path to jquery library? put <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> before your script.

Comment: Have you included the jquery files correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are missing the jquery file ....try this

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #widnow
        {
            width: 400px;
            border: solid 1px;
        }

        #title_bar
        {
            background: #FEFEFE;
            height: 25px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #button
        {
            border: solid 1px;
            width: 25px;
            height: 23px;
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #box
        {
            height: 250px;
            background: #DFDFDF;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button").click(function () {
                if ($(this).html() == "-") {
                    $(this).html("+");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).html("-");
                }
                $("#box").slideToggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="widnow">
        <div id="title_bar">
            Basic information
            <div id="button">
                <img src="http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Minus_in_circle.svg"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found that problem was adding jquery files correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are missing reference to jquery. Replacing your script part with this will solve the problem if that is the case.

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
// or use any version of jquery library..in your fiddle you used 1.7.2..Try the same instead..
<script>
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```